# Proving an inequality

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

The sequence of real numbers $\ a_1,a_2,a_3.....$ is such that $\ a_1=1$ and $$a_{n+1} = \left(a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)^{\!\lambda} $$
where $\ \lambda >1$

Prove by mathematical induction that for $n\geq 2$
$$a_n\geq2^{g(n)} $$
where $g(n) = \lambda^{n-1} $ **Solved**

Prove also that for $\ n\geq 2$, $$  \rm \large \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} > 2^{(\!\lambda-1)g(n)}$$

**Attempt**

$$  \rm \large \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-2^{(\!\lambda-1)g(n)}=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-2^{(\!\lambda-1)g(n)}$$

$$  \rm \large \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-2^{(\!\lambda-1)g(n)}=\frac{\left(a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)^{\!\lambda} }{a_n}-2^{(\!\lambda-1)g(n)}$$

$$  \rm \large \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-2^{(\!\lambda-1)g(n)}=\frac{\left(a_n^2+1\right)^{\!\lambda} }{a_n^{\!\lambda+1}}-2^{(\!\lambda-1)g(n)}$$

$$  \rm \large \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-2^{(\!\lambda-1)g(n)}=\frac{\left(a_n^2+1\right)^{\!\lambda} -2^{(\!\lambda-1)g(n)}\left(a_n^{\!\lambda+1}\right) }{a_n^{\!\lambda+1}}$$

$$  \rm \large \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-2^{(\!\lambda-1)g(n)}=\frac{\left(a_n^2+1\right)^{\!\lambda} -2^{g(n+1)-g(n)}\left(a_n^{\!\lambda+1}\right) }{a_n^{\!\lambda+1}}$$

Now I don't really know how to prove the numerator and denominator to be greater than 0.
Can somebody provide me some hints which would prove beneficial in solving this problem?

Edit:
Denominator might be proved by showing the sequence of the numbers is a monotonically increasing sequence. And since the first term and $\ \lambda $ is greater than 0 than $\ {a_n^{\!\lambda+1}}>0$

Comment: Didn't you just post this question?

Comment: No that was the solved part. This is the second part.

Comment: Also, theres a typo it should be at the start $a_1=1$

Comment: Oh, thank you for noticing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, since $a_n,\lambda>0$
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(a_n+\frac{1}{a_n})^\lambda}{a_n}=\left(a_n^{1-\frac 1\lambda}+a_n^{-1-\frac 1\lambda}\right)^\lambda>\left(a_n^{1-\frac 1\lambda}\right)^\lambda=a_n^{\lambda-1}\ge 2^{(\lambda-1)g(n)}$$
where in the step we have used the conclusion that 
$$a_n\ge 2^{g(n)}.$$